# Wrappanel won't scroll

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I had set the Height of the ScrollViewer but it won't scroll. There are 9 images. The Wrappanel is set to show 2 images per row. But this shows only 3 row ( 6 images). What seems to be the problem?

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"    Height="500">

    <toolkit:WrapPanel Margin="-3,-20,12,-3" Background="White"  ItemHeight="200" Orientation="Horizontal" ItemWidth="200" Height="600" Width="480" FlowDirection="LeftToRight">

    <Image Height="160" Name="image11" Source="/ImgBadges/Badge_1.png" Stretch="UniformToFill" Width="160" />

    <Image Height="160" Name="image12" Source="/ImgBadges/Badge_2.png" Stretch="UniformToFill" Width="160" />

    <Image Height="160" Name="image13" Source="/ImgBadges/Badge_3.png" Stretch="UniformToFill" Width="160" />

    <Image Height="160" Name="image14a" Source="/ImgBadges/Badge_3.png" Stretch="UniformToFill" Width="160" />

    <Image Height="160" Name="image15b" Source="/ImgBadges/Badge_3.png" Stretch="UniformToFill" Width="160" />

    <Image Height="160" Name="image16c" Source="/ImgBadges/Badge_3.png" Stretch="UniformToFill" Width="160" />

     <Image Height="160" Name="image17d" Source="/ImgBadges/Badge_3.png" Stretch="UniformToFill" Width="160" />

     <Image Height="160" Name="image18e" Source="/ImgBadges/Badge_3.png" Stretch="UniformToFill" Width="160" />

     <Image Height="160" Name="image19f" Source="/ImgBadges/Badge_3.png" Stretch="UniformToFill" Width="160" />

    </toolkit:WrapPanel>

</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: What is the parent container of the ScrollViewer ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have forced the height of the `WrapPanel` to 600. Change the height to be set onto the only on the `ScrollViewer`, so that the `WrapPanel` can have infinite space to add more items, while scrolling:

```
<ScrollViewer Height="500" ...>
    <toolkit:WrapPanel ItemHeight="200" Orientation="Horizontal" ItemWidth="200" Width="480" FlowDirection="LeftToRight">
          ...
    </toolkit:WrapPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Summary: remove the height from the WrapPanel, so that more items can be added to it.